# Как устроен Web-Storage в браузере

Tags: javascript, localstorage, storage

Интересует устройство web-storage в браузере. Что представляет собой localstorage и sessionstorage? Полагаю, это какие-то файлы внутри браузера. Так ли это и где они находятся? Какие механизмы контролируют и удаляют содержимое sessiostorage, когда сессия заканчивается?

Спасибо.

Comment: Например, в Chrome localStorage находится в `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять, что такое localStorage, просто представьте, что где-то у вас в браузере встроен такой объект, которым мы можем пользоваться. При этом данный объект не очищает значения, которые мы туда запишем, если мы перезагрузим страницу или даже совсем закроем браузер. По сути localStorage - это свойство глобального объекта браузера (window).

Еще у браузера существует клон localStorage, под названием sessionStorage. Их разница заключается в том, что последний хранит данные только для одной вкладки (сессии) и очистит свое пространство как только мы закроем вкладку.

Подробнее про localStorage можно прочитать здесь:

- http://ustimov.org/posts/16
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage

Comment: Дело в том, что я знаком с этими понятиями, знаю их различие и как ими пользоваться. Меня интересует, как они устроены в браузере. Вы просите представить, что где-то у меня хранится объект. Так вот я хочу конкретно знать, где этот объект находится. В этом и заключается суть моего вопроса.